# Why do I get mongodb.Connect is not a function when connecting to mongodb using node?

Tags: javascript

I want to connect to a mongodb database at cloud.mongodb.com using node.

I get the error mongodb.Connect is not a function. What am I doing wrong here?

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
const mongodb = require("mongodb");

const connectString = "my connection string";
mongodb.Connect(process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING, async function (err, client) {
  const db = client.db();
  const results = await db.collection("pets").find().toArray();
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: It's probably `mongodb.connect`, not `mongodb.Connect`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. The function is `connect`, with a lower-case "c":

```js
mongodb.connect(process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING, async function (err, client) {
  // ---^
  const db = client.db();
  const results = await db.collection("pets").find().toArray();
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: I've gotten flak for answering questions that only have simple typos...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to one or both of these reasons:

- You should import `MongoClient` and not the entire `mongodb` module

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
```

- The method name is `connect` and not `Connect`

Comment: Yes it was MongoClient that was the issue. Thank you for your help