# mongodb.connect is not a function when trying to connect with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

First time using mongodb and i get "mongodb.connect is not a function" when trying to run, what am i doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
let express = require('express')
let mongodb = require('mongodb')

let app = express()
let db

let connectionString = '...' 
mongodb.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, client) {
  db = client.db()
  app.listen(3000)
})
```

Comment: Wrong import? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70584386/why-do-i-get-mongodb-connect-is-not-a-function-when-connecting-to-mongodb-using

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MongoClient to connect, also the callback syntax seems to be behaving weirdly, it's best to use the async await to connect:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

let db;

const url = 'mongodb+srv://';
const dbName = 'dbname';
const client = new MongoClient(url);

(async () => {
    db = (await client.connect()).db(dbName);
    console.log("conected!!");
})();

app.get("/someroute", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await db.collection("yourcollection").findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(req.params.id) });
        res.json(result)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json("Problem");
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server UP");
})
```